# consuming wcf from mvc with js, service works from console, need from js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, model-view-controller

I trying to implement scalable wcf solution without adding service reference. 
So, basically I have service which works fine from my console app as a client or when I'm testing, and now I'm trying to implement mvc client which will communicate to that service over http with help of js. 
My client create proxy which create channel for communication like this

```
IService proxy = new ChannelFactory<IService>(Configuration.MyServiceActiveEndpoint).CreateChannel();
List<MyObjectDto> data = proxy.GetMyData();
```

So, what I actually want to ask is how can I implement this in mvc with help of js.
If you need furher information please let me know.